# Kinect RGB to AVI File

Tags: c#, video, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am attempting to save a video file (e.g., .AVI file)  from the Kinect's RGB stream.

I am using the latest Kinect SDK (1.5)

I tried using e2e's DirectShow filters and it didn't work, there must be a more straight forward approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the colorBasics method of writing each frames as .png files. But, then the speed reduced to 6fps from 30fps. I guess, multi-threading may help to increase the performance. I dont know how to multi thread it, is there any online source of it. I searched a lot, but no luck yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Kinect does not directly support recording straight off the video streams.  You can accomplish it by accessing each frame, as it comes in, and creating an AVI (or other video format) in code.

The [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) has a video recorder, you can look at the source as a starting point.

You can easily extract `WriteableBitmap` objects from the Kinect RGB camera.  From that you can find a lot of information on creating still images to produce an AVI, or produce an AVI directly.

Google Search: [Create AVI from still images](https://www.google.com/search?q=create%20AVI%20from%20still%20images&oq=create%20AVI%20from%20still%20images&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.4851&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Google Search: [Create AVI from WPF WriteableBitmap](https://www.google.com/search?q=create%20AVI%20from%20still%20images&oq=create%20AVI%20from%20still%20images&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.4851&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=Create%20AVI%20from%20WPF%20WriteableBitmap&oq=Create%20AVI%20from%20WPF%20WriteableBitmap&gs_l=serp.3...340207.340207.0.340967.1.1.0.0.0.0.219.219.2-1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.f8oVwe_KjsQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ce986f8e8e81dbe8&bpcl=39468505&biw=1538&bih=1027)

Have a look at the "Color Basics" example from the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit to see how to access the camera and extract data to a `WritableBitmap` object.

Comment: The Kinect does no audio processing, it serves as a microphone only.  Any audio processing, and recording, would be done through the operating system audio API.

Comment: If I got it right. The only way to use kinect as standard webcam is take each rgb image seperately, record a wav file, and then render it myself ?

Comment: Your question is not how "to use kinect as standard webcam"; it is asking how to record video, with the `kinect` and `kinect-sdk` tags - implying you want to do this from a Kinect enabled app you are writing.  In which case, you need to capture each RGB frame (easily done) and write it to an stream that ultimately creates an AVI file (Google search link above).  Adding audio would be something else you could likely do in real-time, which I am sure is documented on MSDN or illustrated elsewhere.

Comment: I've searched "Create AVI from WPF WriteableBitmap" on Google, then I arrived here. So I've clicked on this Create AVI from WPF WriteableBitmap link. And I landed here. So on...